# Guidance on joining 2 dataframes, such that each row of df2 becomes an entire column of df1, iterated over all rows of df2

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to 'multiply' two df's together to create all possible solutions, to use in a Tableau scenario.

The scenario is as follows:

I have a df1 of cars and their associated MPGs, and a df2 of zipcodes, and their associated distance from a fixed point (calculating carbon footprint). Once I get the df3 created I can do more math over the entire df to get to my final metric.

I tried my best below to represent a sample of each df, and the resulting df3 that I am looking to create. df1 is 15,000 rows, and df2 is 535 rows, meaning df3 will have 8m rows.

There may be a better way to do this in tableau; however, I am more comfortable in R.

DF1

```
mpg|year|make |model
--------------------
 21|1985|dodge|charger
 19|1993|Audi |100
```

DF2

```
zipcode|distace
---------------
 20015 | 8.91
 20020 | 12.72
```

DF3

```
mpg|year|make |model  |zipcode|distance
-----------------------------------------
 21|1985|dodge|charger| 20015 |8.91 
 19|1993|Audi |100    | 20015 |8.91
 21|1985|dodge|charger| 20020 |12.72
 19|1993|Audi |100    | 20020 |12.72
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `crossing`

```
library(tidyr)
crossing(DF1, DF2)
#  mpg year  make   model zipcode distance
#1  21 1985 dodge charger   20015     8.91
#2  21 1985 dodge charger   20020    12.72
#3  19 1993  Audi     100   20015     8.91
#4  19 1993  Audi     100   20020    12.72
```

#### data

```
DF1 <- structure(list(mpg = c(21L, 19L), year = c(1985L, 1993L), make = c("dodge", 
"Audi"), model = c("charger", "100")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

DF2 <- structure(list(zipcode = c(20015L, 20020L), distance = c(8.91, 
12.72)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```